# Python read unicode stdin without batching

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython

If I read input from stdin in python, the for loop will collect a number of lines before the body of the loop is run (at least in cpython).

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print("Echo:", line.strip())
```

Outputs:

```
$ python ../test.py 
foo
bar
Echo: foo
Echo: bar
```

Lines are handled in some kind of batches.
I can avoid it like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
    print("Echo:", line.strip())
```

Outputs:

```
$ python ../test.py 
foo
Echo: foo
bar
Echo: bar
```

Which is what I need.

My problem is that I have to read utf-8 input and trick with `iter()` does not work with `codecs.getwriter`.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import codecs

sys.stdin = codecs.getreader('utf-8')(sys.stdin)
for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
    print("Echo:", line.strip())

$ python ../test.py 
foo
bar
Echo: foo
Echo: bar
```

Is there any way to avoid this batching while reading utf8 data from stdin?

---

Edit:
Added import statements for completeness.

Comment: I tried your first example and it doesn't "batch" the way you describe. What system are you on?

Comment: Python 2.x should figure out the encoding for you when you are running in the console. What does `print sys.stdin.encoding` say?

Comment: The first program when run under Python2.7 doesn't produce the output you claim. (It prints `('Echo:', 'foo')` instead.) Which version of Python are you **actually** using?

Comment: I get this behaviour with Python 2.7.3 at Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

Comment: `2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35)`
`[GCC 4.6.3]`
That's exact sys.version output.

Comment: @Robᵩ imports were missing in examples, specifically `from __future__ import print_function`, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lambda`:

```
for line in iter(lambda: sys.stdin.readline().decode('utf-8'), ''):
    print 'Echo:', line.strip()
```

or, decoding in loop body:

```
for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
    print "Echo:", line.decode('utf-8').strip()
```

Comment: I don't understand! How does this fix the problem, especially when we don't know what encoding OP's console has?

Comment: @tdelaney, OP specified `utf-8` in the his/her code.

Comment: @tdelaney, Because the `iter` calls `sys.stdin.readline` until it meets a blank line. http://asciinema.org/a/12470

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `raw_input` to get a line of input from `stdin`.

```
try:
    while True:
        print("Echo:", raw_input())
except EOFError:
    pass
```

The problem is that Python 2 just has this kind of buffering. See the documentation for `-u` on the manpage

```
-u   Force  stdin,  stdout  and stderr to be totally unbuffered.  On systems
     where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and  stderr  in  binary  mode.
     Note  that there is internal buffering in xreadlines(), readlines() and
     file-object iterators ("for line in sys.stdin") which is not influenced
     by   this   option.   To  work  around  this,  you  will  want  to  use
     "sys.stdin.readline()" inside a "while 1:" loop.
```

The important part is that using `sys.stdin.readline()` is the recommended course of action; it's unlikely that there's a good way to forcibly unbuffer file objects.

You should just decode each line as you get it.

Comment: How does unbuffered mode fix the problem?

Comment: @falsetru Yeah, the `print` function was throwing me off. Thanks, this makes the reason more obvious. Unfortunately I realize I'm was off base, too.